# "Se de matización" (por ejemplo, 'bajar vs bajarse') en el español peninsular: ¿cómo entenderlo?

Tags: gramática, verbos, verbo-pronominal, recursos

Estoy intentando entender las diferencias entre verbos como 'bajar' y 'bajarse', 'morir' y 'morirse', 'quedar' y 'quedarse', 'ir' y 'irse', etc.

Con 'ir' y 'irse' se me ha hablado de lo 'incoativo': que la adición de 'se' enfatiza la salida.

Con 'quedar' y 'quedarse' una profesora de español me ha dicho de que 'quedarse' habla de un proceso, mientras 'quedar' habla del resultado.

Con 'morir' y 'morirse', se me ha hablado de la 'participación personal', es decir, que 'morirse' indica que conocemos a la persona personalmente, es decir, que su muerte nos importa.  También la profesora me ha dicho, otra vez, que cuando usamos 'morirse', estamos otra vez más interesados en el proceso, y cuando usamos 'morir' estamos más interesados en el resultado.

Me resulta un poco dispar y confuso.

[Butt](https://www.routledge.com/A-New-Reference-Grammar-of-Modern-Spanish/Butt-Benjamin-Rodriguez/p/book/9781138124011) (4 Ed.) habla del "Se de matización":

> *Se de matización*...refers to the use of the pronominal form to modify the meaning of the original verb in some often unpredictable
> way.  Compare *bajó del árbol* and *se bajó del árbol* '(s)he came
> down from the tree' (the difference between the two is barely
> translatable), or *salió del cine* '(s)he left the cinema' and *se salió
> del cine* '(s)he walked out of the cinema'

Butt sigue con una revisión detallada de unos verbos y su uso con el 'se de matización', que es más bien descriptiva, es decir, trata el asunto como vocabulario.

¿Hay otros recursos que traten el tema?  No he visto nada en la *Nueva Gramática de la lengua española Manual*, tampoco en los dos tomos de Matte Bon.  Quiero saber si hay algún sistema para entender todo esto (es decir, si estamos ante la expresión de 'proceso', la 'participación personal', o otra cosa), más allá de memorizar las dos formas --con y sin *se*-- como vocabulario.  Estoy refiriéndome específicamente al español peninsular.

Comment: Este sitio puede serte de utilidad para ver las distintas caracterizaciones que se hacen del "se": http://hispanoteca.eu/gram%C3%A1ticas/Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/Dativos%20superfluos.htm#:~:text=a)%20Dativo%20de%20recepci%C3%B3n%20o,cort%C3%A9%20el%20c%C3%A9sped%20a%20Maggie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como hablante nativo peninsular, creo  más provechoso aprender de la práctica, que intentar racionalizar cada posible regla, ya que no hay una simple, pero por dar alguna, como "general rule of thumb"  piensa que si termina con «se»  es un verbo pronominal.

Aunque esté detrás, «se» es un **pro**nombre, que al igual que  «te», «me», «nos» y «os» puede ir delante del verbo en todas las formas personales («se acostó») o en una perífrasis verbal («se va a acostar») o detrás, en el imperativo («acuéstese») o en ambas posiciones en gerundios con el verbo estar («se está acostando» = «está acostándose»).

En general, los verbos pronominales suelen ser verbos reflexivos, es decir, cuando **el resultado de la acción recae en el propio sujeto**, esos en cuya traducción podrías añadir "himself", "herself", "yourself", "themselves", "yourselves" o "oneself" sin muchos problemas.
Aunque no siempre son reflexivos, al menos en el sentido estricto del término. También hay formas pasivas o  impersonales, como en «El libro se vende a diez euros» (El libro no se vende a sí mismo, es vendido), pero sería  largo extendernos sobre esto.

En el español es muy común el uso de verbos reflexivos. Y algunos lo son necesariamente (acordarse, quejarse, suicidarse) y otros solo según el contexto, pero significan siempre lo mismo:

> (él)  Va a bajar*se* de la escalera. [reflexivo]

> (él)  Va a bajar la lámpara  [no reflexivo] (baja la lampara, pero «él» quizás no baje con ella).

Otro ejemplo:

> (ellos) Quieren pelear a la menor ocasión. (con el enemigo) [no reflexivo]

> (ellos) Quieren pelearse a la menor ocación. (entre ellos), [reflexivo]

Pero también está el caso más complejo que es cuando al ser reflexivo cambia sustancialmente el significado:

> Va a *quedar* en la fiesta con sus amigos.

> Va a *quedarse* en la fiesta con sus amigos.

¿Lo mismo? ¡Qué va! Traducción:

> Va a *concertar una cita* con sus amigos, en la fiesta.

> Va a *permanecer en* la fiesta, con sus amigos.

Otro buen ejemplo es efectivamente «ir a» o «irse de»:

> No voy a ir a Paris (no voy a trasladarme a Paris)

> No voy a irme de Paris (no voy a marcharme de Paris)

Pero para terminar de complicar las cosas, a veces se puede omitir el pronombre sin cambiar aparentemente el sentido. En [este artículo](https://doi.org/10.4994/hispanica1965.2005.47) dicen que es más frecuente hacerlo en verbos reflexivos como «acostarse», que en indirectos, como «ponerse», pero como sea, yo diría que lo importante es que siempre puede haber alguna sutil diferencia sobre dónde recae la acción, aunque solo en el contexto se puede llegar a apreciar:

> Voy a bajar de las nubes [sin más contexto, reflexivo]

> Voy a bajarme de las nubes [reflexivo]

En este caso, el pronombre solo enfatiza que la acción recae  sobre el sujeto (yo) y quizás sea superfluo, o quizás sea que empleo «me» porque hablo de volver a la dura realidad, y no de hacer descender al dron que estoy pilotando, en el que no estoy realmente.